# Visual Studio Project References inside solution

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

What is the best way to reference a project inside solution.

I added references via Add Reference --> Projects. However it links to either release DLL or Debug dll.

I want to have project itself in the reference, when we compile the projects, all the references projects must be compiled (through dependencies).

How to do this?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to reference a project itself, and NOT a DLL/assembly (from the Browse tab in the Add Reference dialog), then you should add the project you want to reference to the Solution (Add... Existing Project). Once it's in the Solution, the Add Reference dialog will let you reference one project in the solution from another project in the solution (via the Projects tab in the Add Reference dialog).

Comment: One of the reasons the poster may have asked this is that once you add a project to your solution, it takes as much space in the Project Explorer as your "real" project(s).  Do you know if there's a way to make them look, um, smaller?

Comment: it's in a tree view, so you can collapse the project if you don't want to view it.

Comment: He said that's how he was referencing it already.  He's using the Projects tab.