# Adding XUI for UI interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, xna

I am a newbie in writing a small code using XNA and want to use XUI in my code. But the instruction on XUI website is so simple and I am not sure about how to do it. Here is the instruction from the introduction:

"Add the XUI libraries to your solution, then add a reference to it in your main project.
Add the XUIContent project to your solution, then add a Content Reference to it in your main project."

Could anybody give me some explanation on it please? Its link is here
http://xui.codeplex.com/documentation

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Adding references to a project?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. From the beginning, "Adding XUI libraries to solution", Is it like adding class in solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can contain multiple projects, and that's what you want to do here. Add the XUI project to your solution, then right-click references for your main project and add a reference to the XUI project.

Do the same steps for the XUIContent project.

Here's how to [add an existing project to a solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179467%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Reference [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322998/1141432) to see how to add a reference to another project in the same solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, before adding project, it says "Add the XUI libraries to your solution, then add a reference to it in your main project", what does it mean please?

Comment: "Add the XUI libraries to your solution" means "add the XUI project to your solution".

Comment: Thanks, almost there, last question, after "Add the XUI project to your solution", what does "right-click references for your main project and add a reference to the XUI project." mean please?