# Visual Studio C# Project-to-project Reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have two .NET Framework libraries in the same solution. If I set project A as a dependency of project B is there a way to get it to copy over the dll when I build the solution?

Thanks,

Comment: It should do it automatically.

Comment: You don't need to worry, it will do it due to the dependency.

Comment: You must see the dll in build directly for project B

Comment: It is not doing it automagically... :-( 
Both projects are .NET 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Project References inside solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322992/visual-studio-project-references-inside-solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer (which I think is mentioned in many other areas but cryptically).

**The following must be done in addition to declaring a project dependency.**

In the **Reference Manager** (*Solution>References>Add Reference*) you can select a project from your solution and reference that directly. It will handle all of the updating of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, build a project as a library, then take the dll and import it into the project you want to use

Comment: The only problem with that is you need to continually update the dll w/e the depended upon project gets rebuilt. The right way is to declare a reference in the Reference Manager,

Comment: certain in part, if the project to be instantiated is just generic functions, then it does not need to be updated. If it is of mutable functions then better reference the project than the DLL.